# Time Format get changed while importing data from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

I have two questions:
 1. I have created one DB table in which a column name TIME specified as `time(7)` (i.e. `00:00:00`) data type. When I import the data from SQL to Excel, time is getting formatted in `00:00:00.0000000` format. Could anyone help on this why it is doing so.
[image]
 2. When I correct the data format, save my file as CSV and trying to update data with SQL Import & Export Data, I still have to manually charge the format of TIME column in advance properties of source data to database time. Any solution so I do not have to do it every time.

Comment: Format the cells in Excel before import, then save the file as a template. Then when you need to import the data to Excel, use that template and they will be formatted properly.

Comment: What's that you use in order to export and import? If you're not playing with "START_TIME" column, I'd keep it as a string for import and export so you don't have to change the format. If you need to sort or update "START_TIME" column on excel sheet, you may have to change the format of excel sheet on the way you wanna show. Sorting should be fine even in the string format.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. time(7) - 7 is the fractional seconds precision. time(0) is 00:00:00

So by defining it as time(7) you're getting the extra .0000000 that you don't want. Try CASTing to time(0) and it should remove everything after the decimal point.